# C++ CPU usage percentage spikes

Tags: c++, windows, cpu, cpu-usage

I wrote the code below to get the current cpu usage on a window machine. However I notice some unusual spikes. Nine out of ten times the percentage I'm getting is between 2-5 and suddenly it spikes to over 95% which ofc doesn't agree with what the task-manger is showing... Could someone please point out if there is anything I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

float roundPercentage(const double& d) {

    std::ostringstream tmp;

    tmp << d;

    std::string str = tmp.str();

    return (float)(std::round(std::stof(str.substr(0, 5)) * 100) / 100);

}

int main() {

    while (true) {
        FILETIME idle_time, kernel_time, user_time;
        std::vector<FILETIME> last_values;
        GetSystemTimes(&idle_time, &kernel_time, &user_time);
        last_values.push_back(kernel_time);
        last_values.push_back(user_time);

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));

        GetSystemTimes(&idle_time, &kernel_time, &user_time);
        unsigned long long current_value = (kernel_time.dwLowDateTime + kernel_time.dwHighDateTime) + (user_time.dwLowDateTime + user_time.dwHighDateTime);
        unsigned long long last_value = (last_values[0].dwLowDateTime + last_values[0].dwHighDateTime) + (last_values[1].dwLowDateTime + last_values[1].dwHighDateTime);

        double d = (double)(last_value - current_value) / (double)(last_value + current_value) * 100.0;

        std::cout << "cpu usage: " << roundPercentage(d) << "%" << std::endl;
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `dwLowDateTime + dwHighDateTime` is a bullshit calculation that doesn't do anything useful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is dwLowDateTime and dwHighDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266743/what-is-dwlowdatetime-and-dwhighdatetime)

Comment: Yeap I should have looked into that first

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments I had a better look into `FILETIME` and `ULARGE_INTEGER` and the below code seems to work...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>

uint64_t FromFileTime(const FILETIME& ft) {
    ULARGE_INTEGER uli = { 0 };
    uli.LowPart = ft.dwLowDateTime;
    uli.HighPart = ft.dwHighDateTime;
    return uli.QuadPart;
}

int main() {


    while (true) {
        
        FILETIME idle_time, kernel_time, user_time;
                
        GetSystemTimes(&idle_time, &kernel_time, &user_time);
        
        uint64_t k1 = FromFileTime(kernel_time);
        uint64_t u1 = FromFileTime(user_time);
        uint64_t i1 = FromFileTime(idle_time);

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));

        GetSystemTimes(&idle_time, &kernel_time, &user_time);

        uint64_t k2 = FromFileTime(kernel_time);
        uint64_t u2 = FromFileTime(user_time);
        uint64_t i2 = FromFileTime(idle_time);

        
        uint64_t ker = k2 - k1;
        uint64_t usr = u2 - u1;
        uint64_t idl = i2 - i1;

        uint64_t cpu = (ker + usr - idl) * 100 / (ker + usr);

        std::cout << "cpu usage: " << static_cast<int>(cpu) << "%" << std::endl;
        
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```